# how to find column name of specific value from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

```
Input 1000
```

```
output
A :5/10/20
B :5/10/20
C :5/18/20
D :5/12/20
```

and so on....

I have dataframe

```
state  5/10/20  5/11/20  5/12/20   5/13/20  5/14/20  5/15/20  5/16/20  5/17/20  5/18/20

A      1000     5000     4522      5200     3300     1200     5200     6933     5200

B      1000     5500     1002      9200     3350     1800     5266     6301     9600

C      1200     5599     1500      2000     3011     1963     3011     6300     1000

D      1088     5500     1000      9200     3350     1800     5266     6301     9600

E      1011     3300     1080      5230     9633     2222     6330     9622     1400
```

Answer (score 1):

In the case of multiple matches, or no matches per row, use `where` + `stack`. `where` will `NaN` anything not equal to your value, then `stack` gives you a MultiIndex (row_label, col_label) and drops all `NaN`.

```
value = 1000

df = df.set_index('state')
df.where(df.eq(value)).stack()
```

---

```
state         
A      5/10/20    1000.0
B      5/10/20    1000.0
C      5/18/20    1000.0
D      5/12/20    1000.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: thank you this work for me, Is it possible to search between two values in same dataframe.

Comment: @user10961148 yes instead of `.eq` you could do `df.where(df.ge(XX) & df.le(YY)).stack()`. Those stand for less than or equal to and greater than or equal to respectively.